# Javascript: $.ajax is null inside the for loop

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have an onclick function btn-book, and inside it is a for loop for the data of Ajax. I'm sure that data have values but i dont get it why i always get null. here is the code of the onclick.

```
$('#mapContainer').on('click', '.btn-book', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = e.currentTarget.id;
    var routeOrigin = route_Search.origin;
    routeOrigin = routeOrigin.filter(function(e){return e}); 
    var url = base_url;

    for(var i = 1; i <= desNo; i++){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                data: {
                    id: id,

                    origin: $('#route-origin'+i).val(),
                    origin_contactperson: $('#origin-contactperson'+i).val(),
                    origin_company: $('#origin-company'+i).val(),
                    origin_phonenumber: $('#origin-phonenumber'+i).val(),
                    origin_notes: $('#origin-notes'+i).val(),
                    origin_Lng: routeOrigin[i-1].lng(),
                    origin_Lat: routeOrigin[i-1].lat(),
                },
                success: function(msg)
                {   
                    console.log(msg);
                },
                error: function()
                {
                    alert("An error occured while updating. Try again in a while");
                }
            })

    }

});
```

Comment: are you saying that the success code `console.log(msg);` logs `null`? that would mean the server is returning nothing ... are there any errors in the browser console when you run this code?

Comment: yes, the msg is null. there is no any errors in the browser console when i run the code

Comment: also, does your HTML have input elements with **id**s exactly like `route-origin1` and `origin-contactperson1` and `origin-company1` and `origin-phonenumber1` and `origin-notes1` ? Hard to tell since you didn't post any HTML

Comment: so - in your browser developer tools, can you see what the request is returning in the body of the response? and does the request body look correct?

Comment: @JaromandaX i only add route-origin1 and origin-contactperson1 and origin-company1 and origin-phonenumber1 and origin-notes1 inputs with a button.

Comment: @JaromandaX i'm sorry but what do you mean request body? do you mean the data?

Comment: Why you need to use ajax in the loop?  This is not good practice to use it in loop. You need to collect in some array and the do ajax request.

Comment: you shouldn't have put your ajax call inside for look. You can debug your server code and send ajax request without the for loop. see what do you get in server and what are you sending as response and let us know.

Comment: "yes, the msg is null." — So the server responds with null. Why do you expect it to respond with anything else? What does the server side code look like? What does the HTTP request you send looking like? You need to provide a complete [mcve]

Comment: a POST request has a body (could be called "params" in the developer tools), which is the data, yes

Answer (score -2):

use like this.

```
 $('#mapContainer').on('click', '.btn-book', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var id = e.currentTarget.id;
        var routeOrigin = route_Search.origin;
        routeOrigin = routeOrigin.filter(function(e){return e}); 
        var url = base_url;
        var origin = [], origin_contactperson = []

        for(var i = 1; i <= desNo; i++){
             origin.push($('#route-origin'+i).val());
             origin_contactperson.push($('#origin-contactperson'+i).val());
                .....
        }

         $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: url,
                    data: {
                        id: id,

                        origin: origin,
                        origin_contactperson: origin_contactperson,
                        origin_company: origin_company,
                        origin_phonenumber: origin_phonenumber,
                        origin_notes: origin_notes,
                        origin_Lng: origin_Lng,
                        origin_Lat: origin_Lat
                    },
                    success: function(msg)
                    {   
                        console.log(msg);
                    },
                    error: function()
                    {
                        alert("An error occured while updating. Try again in a while");
                    }
                })

    });
```

Comment: This reads more like a game of spot-the-difference than an answer. What did you change? Why should it solve the problem?

Comment: It *looks* like you've completely restructured the way the data is sent to the server without changing the server to expect the new format of the data … but aside from breaking everything horribly by doing so, I don't understand why whatever value the OP said was `null` before wouldn't still be `null`.

Comment: Please look accurate to the code. I assume it is not the same and no need to find the difference. First of all I collect all needed fields. The second I moved the ajax from loop(this is the main reason why it is solved the problem).

Comment: If you do ajax call in loop you every time open the connection for it. I assume it would be better to collect all data before send to server.

Comment: While that's nice in theory, it only works if you also change the server side code to expect the data to be sent that way … and since it looks like the server side code doesn't work in the first place, that isn't helping!